# Android SDK manager is not responding when I click on SDK tools

Tags: android, android-studio

When I tried to click on SDK Tools and SDK platforms it's not even responding.

In order to download the components, what should I do?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

change your sdk location, (sangeeth kumar) it should not contain whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

There is a white space in your SDK Location remove that.

Replace your location:

```
C:\Users\sangeeth kumar\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
```

With this :

```
C:\Users\sangeethkumar\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
```